# How to ensure seamless usability on the front-end when deploying an SPA?

Tags: webpack, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I expect this applies to any web framework using webpack that builds assets / chunks, in my case it's Vue.

My workflow is:

1. Develop a feature
2. Build (npm run build)
3. Deploy (eb deploy)
4. Back to 1.

Building removes all previous chunks as adds new ones i.e.

my-module.1X3DF23.js
my-other-module.9DFdw232.js

If a user was on the front end at this same time without refreshing the page (SPA, so unlikely) and browses to a new view that depends on a chunk that's been wiped, they get a 404 for those missing old assets.

Until this point, I have been incrementing a version number along with any XHR requests from the server. If the app notices a change, it will reload itself. But if 404 errors are coming up from chunks, no XHR requests will be called anyway.

Initial thoughts:

1. Have the web app ping the back-end with an interval of say 30 seconds, this would trigger the version refreshing automatically.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with not deleting previous chunks at all. I don't know how elasticbeanstalk works so I will show you my strategy with a good old ubuntu server.

Basically, you have those folders in your Vue application:

```
dist -> Contains the content of the built application with npm run build
node_modules
public
src
...
```

What I do is that I create a new folder named `deploy` because one problem of the `dist` folder is that `npm run build` deletes the content of the `dist` folder at the beginning of build.

Having the `deploy` folder, you can keep all the data needed across time.

So when I build my project, I then copy the content of the dist folder into the deploy folder without deleting previous chunks.

In order to avoid the `deploy` folder to interfere with git, I add it to the `.gitignore` registry.

You can do this with a simple recursive paste using bash:

```
cp -R dist/* deploy/
```

This will replace your `index.html` page into the deploy folder but will not overwrite your previous chunks.

**Problem with this solution:** Your `deploy` folder might get huge because previous chunks would never be deleted.

**Solution for this problem:** Write a robust script that deletes chunks older than 1 day (or more) when deploying the application. You can base your script on the creation date of the file. If you are fluent with bash, go with it. I personally prefer to write this kind of script with node directly in a `deploy.js` script at the root of my project..

Comment: Viable solution. I could setup up an .ebextensions script that could keep the latest 5 sets of chunks. Will wait a couple more days in case someone else chimes in but you're a strong contender for the 50 coins o' gold.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you doing the following

Consider a static URL resource that you serve as follows

> abc.com/v1/module.123.js

I would suggest you to keep the

> v1

Part as same inbetween your build updates.

Webpack will generate a new file name as follows

> build1: module.123.js
>
> build2: module.234.js

whenever the content of module.js changes inbetween your builds.

During your build updates make sure you are not removing your

> v1

folder in your server. Rather doing a complete replacement you can merge the old folder and new folder. By doing this you will be having both

> module.123.js
>
> module.234.js

in your v1 folder in the server. By doing this you will avoid the http 404 error in the SPA.

You can notify the user of a build update through another process, and asking him to refresh the browser to get the changes. This notification of changes to the user can be done using a [Server Sent Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

You can change the V1 folder every 6 months or so to V2 or something else that suits your needs to clean up unused files.

Answer (score -1):

If your application is a 100% static application, you can use AWS S3 bucket. To update you application you just need to update your repo.

aws s3 sync --delete /source /destiny

We have been doing this and the update is seamless as you expect.

Comment: Not sure you understand the requirement. It's about dealing with a view that a user might have loaded which references chunks that get overwritten on deploy. If they haven't reloaded their page, old routes to chunks will be queried and 404 will be returned.

Comment: Not quite... If you have configured your chunks to have the hash in their names, the browser will not pull the new files unless this hash code has been changed/updated.

If you use cloudFront they also have their internal cache in which you can use in your favour.